# validating structure of Firebase JSON before saving

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-security

I'm getting my feet wet with Firebase.  I have a very strong MS SQL Server database background.  How do you validate the JSON data being saved in Firebase to match a particular structure?  Is there a way to apply an 'interface' to the JSON to make sure we have the correct structure?  Otherwise, how do you have any confidence in the data being saved?

Comment: [Security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/) include .validate rules for enforcing schema. There's an informative guide to get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema! Sounds like you'd love [the Bolt compiler](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-11-09-introducing-the-bolt-compiler.html)!

**The Bolt compiler is how you express schema in Firebase.**

With Bolt, you can express types as schema and then apply it the path where the data is stored.

```
// Create the schema for a Post type
type Post {
  title: String;
  author: String;
  description: String;
  timestamp: Number;
  isPublished: Boolean;
}

// All data stored at "/posts" will conform to the Post type above
path /posts is Post;
```

There's also a [quick-start](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html) and [guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/guide.html) to help you get started.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for providing a direction.